# grep "Input/output error" less "read error" with plain text files in home directory

Tags: macos, bash, file-io

I downloaded a bunch of text files from the [Google Books Ngrams](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html) dataset: the Russian 1-grams from 2009, to be exact. I can open, read, and search most of the files with `less` and `grep`, but when I try to search within some files in `less` ( <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>Э</kbd> ), then after getting some results, I get `read error (press RETURN)`. If I use grep, the same files give a similar error:

```
$ grep Э googlebooks-rus-all-1gram-20090715-5.csv
...
(lots of results)
...
grep: googlebooks-rus-all-1gram-20090715-5.csv: Input/output error
```

Searching the internet for this error, everyone seems to be having issues with searching their entire file system, and getting into trouble with `/proc`, devices, etc. However, this is just a simple text file inside my home directory. Why am I getting this error, and what is a workaround?

Comment: Could you grep an uuencoded file, so it will not contain "difficult" characters? I do not think Russian is simple text and grep agrees with me.

Comment: @WalterA I'm not sure what you mean by "unencoded file" or "difficult characters". The cyrillic alphabet is represented in unicode as sequences of bytes, just like the latin alphabet. `grep` will happily find cyrillic letters in other files, so there is something wrong with these files.

Comment: [`uuencode`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) is a text-only encoding from the dark ages.

Comment: @bebop: That wouldn't cause an I/O error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're encountering a real I/O error with the drive. Back up anything of import. Check `sudo less /var/log/system.log` to see if the kernel is reporting disk I/O errors. Try verifying the disk and volume using Disk Utility, but it only checks the partition map and directory structures. It doesn't look for bad sectors or a generally failing drive. It can show S.M.A.R.T. status for some drives, though. Try [Apple Hardware Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18765).

You can try `fsck_hfs -S` which supposedly scans for I/O errors. I've never used it. You'd probably want to do this while booted to single user mode.

Comment: This was, in fact, the case. Apple Hardware Diagnostics didn't show any problems. I used `SMART Utility.app` (https://www.volitans-software.com/apps/smart-utility/) and it showed lots of bad sectors. Glad I caught it early!! Thanks.